# Do I need to release or free the map out of the function?

Tags: memory, dictionary, go

I am new to golang, and I made a function which returns a map, but I do not know if it will cause a memory leak. the code like below

```
func ParseParams(data string) map[string]string {

    params := strings.Split(data, "&")

    m := make(map[string]string)

    for idx := range params {

        vals := strings.Split(params[idx], "=")
        m[vals[0]] = vals[1]
    }

    return m    
}
```

So, I would like to know if it is necessary to release or free the map ? or do something to avoid the memory leak.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about memory leaks in Go, unless you do something super special.

Comment: Perfectly fine. Go will handle this for you.

Comment: See [ParseQuery](http://godoc.org/net/url#ParseQuery) for a function that does something similar to your example.

Answer (score 2):

Go is garbage-collected so there is no possibility of a memory leak here.